# How to parse this xml to java object (Retrofit2+SimpleXML)? (PersistenceException error)

Tags: android, xml, retrofit2, simple-framework, simple-xml-converter

my Retrofit call failed with error :

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Element 'item' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(data=false, empty=true, entry=, inline=false, name=item, required=false, type=void) on field 'medias' private java.util.ArrayList packageName.FeedTag.medias at line 58
```

which I guessed is caused by incorrectly mapping the XML to POJO class.

So, can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? I've tried looking at SimpleXML examples and tutorial but I can't find info with the use case such as mine. (This is my first time working with Retrofit and/or SimpleXML.)

This is my XML

```
<xml>
<feed>
<item>
  <id>0</id>
  <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
</item>

<item>
  <id>1</id>
  <title>Lorem ipsum dolor</title>
  <comments>
     <item>
        <id>3</id>
     </item>
  </comments>
  <medias>
     <item>
       <id>4</id>
       <title>Media 1</title>
     </item>

      <item>
        <id>8</id>
        <title>Media 2</title>
      </item>
    </medias>
  </item>

</feed>
</xml>
```

My objects is like this :

**XmlTag.java**

```
@Root(name = "item", strict = false)
public class XmlTag{

   @Path("feed")
   @ElementList(name = "item", required = false)
   private List<FeedTag> feeds;

   //empty constructor, setter, getter...    

}
```

**FeedTag.java**

```
@Root(name = "item", strict = false)
public class FeedTag{

   @Element(name = "title", required = false)
   private String title;

   @Path("comments")
   @ElementList(name = "item", required = false)
   private List<CommentTag> comments;

   @Path("medias")
   @ElementList(name = "item", required = false)
   private List<MediaTag> medias;

   //empty constructor, setter, getter...    

}
```

and CommentTag and MediaTag are similar to FeedTag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found what's wrong with my code after some T&Es.

It was because of the `@ElementList(name = "item", required = false)` line doesn't have `inline=true` in it. From my trial and error, with that parameter, simplexml only parse direct `<item/>` child of the given `@Path', so other tags with same tag name is safe as their`` tag hasn't been used yet by other tags.

So, as long as I make sure that any `@ElementList` of tags that have possible duplicate tag name has `inline=true`, the `PersistenceException` I got before won't return.